# Android Floating EditBox

Tags: android, editbox

I have an OptionMenu which has single option in it named "Search". When the search option is clicked, it should dynamically add a EditText at the top of Activity window like it has in WebView (browser address bar) so users could search something in my application.

After there would be EditBox, one can write inside it. I also want to have some OnTextChanged like event of that EditBox so do you think it's also available with that View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it myself. I added an EditText on the screen with setting as hidden and on button click made it visible. It worked like a charm.